# HTTPS endpoints not working in Service Fabric local cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am able to run a stateless service in a local service fabric cluster. However, when I add an https end point, activation fails.

I made the following changes:

ServiceManifest.xml:

```xml
<Endpoint Name="ServiceEndpoint" Type="Input" Protocol="https" Port="443" CertificateRef="my_api_cert" />
```

ApplicationManifest.xml:

```xml
<Policies>
  <EndpointBindingPolicy EndpointRef="ServiceEndpoint" CertificateRef="my_api_cert" />
</Policies>
<Certificates>
  <EndpointCertificate X509FindValue="[Api_SslCertHash]" Name="my_api_cert" />
</Certificates>
```

I have uploaded the newly created certificate to Local Machine\My store too.

I get the following error in cluster manager:

> Error event: SourceId='System.Hosting', Property='Activation:1.0:1.0'.
>   There was an error during activation.

What could be the solution for this issue?

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? I am stuck with a similar problem where activation fails on my secure cluster (but https works fine locally)

Comment: Is this a cert issue?

Comment: Port 443 is probably in use. Probably by Skype. Open Skype, Tools -> Options -> Advanced -> Connection and tick off "Use port 80 and 443 for additional incoming connections"

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact same issue and my problem was that I was not passing the correct thumbprint in ApplicationManifest.xml. **Make sure your [Api_SslCertHash] has the correct cert thumbprint.**

In EventViewer > Microsoft Service Fabric, I saw this:

> Failed to configure port certificate for port: [my port], certificatefindvalue [my wrong cert thumbprint], error 0x80070520

If you google this error code, you'll see it has to do with binding SSL with IIS or something similar. So that narrowed it down to the certificate and then I realized I was not using the correct cert.

Check and see if you missed anything: http://ronaldwildenberg.com/running-an-azure-service-fabric-cluster-locally-on-ssl/ This link is a step by step tutorial to adding https to a service fabric service and you can use it as a check list.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: I updated my answer with the solution that worked for me.

Comment: Thanks ! Made me realize i had installed the wrong certificate

Answer (score 3):

As others have mentioned, this can happen when the certificate thumbprint is incorrect. However there is one specific reason for the thumbprint to be incorrect that can be so frustrating to figure out it deserves its own answer.

I'll quote [TChiang phorego (Partner) from the MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/83a4ef4d-4b89-4ba9-9a2d-0ed4e37fdb9a/https-endpoints-not-working-in-service-fabric-local-cluster?forum=AzureServiceFabric) (emphasis mine):

> The trick is that **when you copy the thumbprint from the certificate
>   store, it comes with some hidden characters in the front** (when I place
>   the cursor at the front and press <- the cursor will not advance
>   left), so when you paste it into the manifest, SF cannot install the
>   service. So just make sure you remove the hidden characters and then
>   it will be ok.

Comment: omg please kill me. Anyway, characters best removed using the binary viewer built into VS (right click the manifest and select Open With...)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following to the applicationmanifest.xml

```
  <ServiceManifestImport>
        <ServiceManifestRef ServiceManifestName="WebApiServicePkg" ServiceManifestVersion="1.0.0" />
        <ConfigOverrides />
        <Policies>
          <EndpointBindingPolicy CertificateRef="SslCert" EndpointRef="ServiceEndpoint" />
        </Policies>
  </ServiceManifestImport>
  <Certificates>
    <EndpointCertificate Name="SslCert" X509FindValue="[SslCert_Thumbprint]" X509StoreName="My" />
  </Certificates>
```

Comment: My applicationmanifest.xml has all the items you have specified but still not getting. Is it even possible to run https api in a local cluster?

Comment: I have done it just fine. Reused the localhost certificate that IIS Express also uses. Remember to use the cert thumbprint, easiest way to get is to use the following powershell cmd: Get-ChildItem cert:\LocalMachine\My

Comment: Maybe I copied it to Trusted Root Certs as well to make it work, in order to establish full trust for the certificate. Can have a look at work computer tomorrow.